# How to store pig output to the hive table?

Tags: csv, azure, hadoop, apache-pig

I have HDInsight cluster on Azure and `.csv` files in hdfs (Azure storage).

Using apache-pig I want to process these files and store the output in a hive table. To achieve this I have written following script:

```
A = LOAD '/test/input/t12007.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (year:chararray,ArrTime:chararray,DeptTime:chararray);
describe A;
dump A;
store A into 'testdb.tbl3' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

This script loads the file successfully, describe the structure and it also displays the data using dump but while store command executes it throws the following error:

```
2017-05-02 06:18:41,476 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error during parsing. Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: <file script.pig, line 4, column 33> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.] 
Caused by: <file script.pig, line 4, column 33> pig script failed to validate: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.] 
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.] 
2017-05-02 06:18:41,484 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Comment: try running your script using:

pig -useHCatalog your_scriptname.pig

Comment: i am executing the script in ambari.
i added the -useHCatalog argument while executing the script.

Answer (score 1):

`pig -useHCatalog`

From the Pig HCatalog [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore)

**Running Pig with HCatalog**

Pig does not automatically pick up `HCatalog` jars. To bring in the necessary jars, you can either use a flag in the pig command or set the environment variables `PIG_CLASSPATH` and `PIG_OPTS` as described below. To bring in the appropriate jars for working with `HCatalog`, simply include the following flag in your script:

**Alternate way:**

Specify the location of the `HCatalog` jar and add a `REGISTER` statement with the path of the jar to the top of your script as below.

```
REGISTER /usr/username/client/lib/hive-hcatalog-core-1.2.1.2.3.0.0-2557.jar;
```

Your path may be different as per installation in your cluster. You can find this jar location using command: `locate *hcatalog-core*`

**HCatStorer**

`HCatStorer` is used with Pig scripts to write data to `HCatalog-managed` tables.

**Usage**

`HCatStorer` is accessed via a Pig store statement.

```
STORE A INTO 'tablename'
   USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Comment: i am executing the script in ambari. i have added -useHCatalog as an argument. still it gives error.

Comment: Is your Hive table exists ? If not you need to create table first.